# Who has creative control of Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, canon, disney

Before he sold the rights to Disney, George Lucas was the ultimate word of God in the *Star Wars* universe.

Now we have a corporation who owns it. There are any number of writers and directors looking involved. Does anyone have ultimate creative control?

Is there a plan that the stories fit into, or is it being made up as they go along?

Comment: Note: while Lucas had ultimate control over the SW universe before selling to Disney, he wasn't that involved in maintaining the continuity in the expanded universe. It was really only the three prequels he created that overrode that continuity.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Primarily, Disney via the Lucasfilm Story Group...

The Lucasfilm Story Group is a division of Lucasfilm, created after the Disney acquisition; it's [their job](https://twitter.com/HolocronKeeper/status/420071186232385536) to keep the *Star Wars* canon as internally consistent as possible, and to guide its development.

Pablo Hidalgo, a member of the LSG and one of the "[continuity trio](https://twitter.com/HolocronKeeper/status/816057377325625344)" sub-group, commented [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/801889710788349952) that much of his job involves high-level storyline planning, and making notes on new in-progress stories:

[image]

> **@MisterCHolocron** What exactly does being creative executive entail? I assume it's basically being an editor of sorts for books?
>
> **@pablohidalgo** planning storylines, all content, reading/approving/commenting on scripts, manuscripts, outlines, etc. etc.

### ...but writers have the freedom to tell the stories they want to tell

However, Lucasfilm affords a great deal of creative leeway to the individual creators; as a [Slashfilm article](http://www.slashfilm.com/lucasfilm-story-group-star-wars-canon/) reports, based on the LSG live panel from Celebration Anaheim 2015, and as Hidalgo notes [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/818268846008061952), the Story Group doesn't dictate stories, just provides makes sure stories are being told at the right time:

> The first point made at the panel was that the Story Group has a long game plan. They have major beats and ideas spanning probably years or maybe decades in advance (Note: no specific time frame was given) so as to be able to incorporate everything Star Wars is becoming.
>
> *[...]*
>
> While the term “Story Group” may make it sound like they are dictating the story, that’s not usually the case. In most cases, authors or filmmakers who are hired to work on Star Wars properties, are given the oppurtunity *[sic]* to come up with their own stories and ideas. While doing that, they work closely with the Story Group to make sure the stories are authentically Star Wars (for example, Darth Vader doesn’t dance or something) and also fit into the larger plan. Hidalgo said they’ve heard pitches from people who have great ideas for characters who are then told, “Come back in six years.” That’s because the story they’re pitching would fit in better with a character at another point in the future.

[image]

> **@bishbashboshjt** Do LFL tell novelists the plot or do they Vet it with you?
>
> **@pablohidalgo** We don't tell them the plot. It's their stories. We just try to make sure it's the right story to tell at the right time.

Although the LSG has a long-term plan for how the *Star Wars* universe will unfold, the fine details are left in the hands of the individual creators (in close consultation with the LSG, to keep the canon consistent).

Comment: Now you've got me imagining a Jedi vs. Sith dance-off.

Comment: @JAB https://i.ytimg.com/vi/qXp8T097vjc/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: I meant one that involves use of the Force. Having to dance while simultaneously trying to discreetly interfere with your opponent's dancing and avoid being interfered with yourself.

Comment: First is Vader's turn. He does pretty well. Then Luke goes. While he's dancing amazingly, the Emperor starts messing with him - making him look like a fool. Vader, overcome by emotion by his son's incredible dancing, but furious at the Emperor's tampering; gets pissed and throws the Emperor down the nearest reactor shaft... "*Come back in another 6 years with that idea*"

Comment: So Luke is a "dancin' fool"?

Answer (score 10):

Disney announced this via [StarWars.com](http://www.starwars.com/news/the-legendary-star-wars-expanded-universe-turns-a-new-page) some time ago.

The [Lucasfilm Story Group](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lucasfilm_Story_Group), created by Kathleen Kennedy, oversees all aspects of creativity and story telling within the Star Wars universe.

This allows the story group to maintain a cohesive canon universe across multiple mediums.

> Now, with an exciting future filled with new cinematic installments of Star Wars, all aspects of Star Wars storytelling moving forward will be connected. Under Lucasfilm President Kathleen Kennedy’s direction, the company for the first time ever has formed a story group to oversee and coordinate all Star Wars creative development.
>
> “We have an unprecedented slate of new Star Wars entertainment on the horizon,” said Kennedy. “We’re set to bring Star Wars back to the big screen, and continue the adventure through games, books, comics, and new formats that are just emerging. This future of interconnected storytelling will allow fans to explore this galaxy in deeper ways than ever before.”

Comment: Not to be a pedant, but the plural of "medium" is "media." :)